# Strike out a word in javascript when item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Strike out a word in javascript/jquery when item clicked.

So I am clicking and item ,the item fades out but in the same time I want the text to strike out.

Ex. I have an apple(image) and a apple(text). When I click on the apple I want the image to fade out and the text to strike out.

```
<div id="items">
  <p>Apple</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="box" id="pic1"> <img src = /images/apple.png  /></div>
    <script>
      $("#pic1").click(function () {
        $("#pic1").fadeOut("slow");
       });
    </script>
```

This is my code until the image fades out but I cannot figure out how can I make the text to strike out???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ab2gy/)**

You could wrap the text in `<del>`

```
$("#pic1").click(function () {
 $("#items p").wrap("<del>");
 $("#pic1").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 26):

Try putting this after the fade.

```
$(this).parents("p").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
```

Comment: As <strike></strike> is not a valid HTML5 tag, this should now be marked as the most correct answer. Thanks, @tymeJV!