# If the word is in a certain class set style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

example code

```
<ul class="learnt">
    <li>potato</li>
    <li>carrot</li>
</ul>
```

I want to write a paragraph which puts strikes through the words with a certain class.

example of what i want displayed: "I have a <strike>carrot</strike> and a <strike>potato</strike> in my farm."

Can I use JS or CSS to do this without "strike" tags and without putting crosses through the list?

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891011/strike-out-a-word-in-javascript-when-item-clicked

Comment: This puts a strike through anything between the dives, I only want certain words crossed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this was what you need. You must iterate over the ul elements:

```
$('.learnt li').each(function() {
    ...
}
```

And then replace each one in the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/V3ehU/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In CSS do the following:

```
.learnt{
    text-decoration:line-through;
    list-style: none;   
}
```

Comment: How can i add words to this class though?

Comment: If you only want certain words then you could do it with a span tag like so:

    <li>This is a <span class="learnt">word</span></li>. the word "word" will now have a strike through